# Wildcard based existential types in Scala3

Tags: scala, type-safety, existential-type, scala-3

As noted in the [Scala 3 docs](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/existential-types.html) existential types which cannot be expressed by wildcards are generally dropped. Here is my code in

***Scala 2***

```
trait Test[A]

val t: T forSome { type T <: Test[Int] } = null //fine
```

[Demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ck9IvDJSSk2NxgdcwLrqAw)

***Scala 3***

Trying to rewrite it in Scala 3 using wildcard:

```
trait Test[A]

val t: _ <: Test[Int]  = null //error: Unbound wildcard type
```

[Demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WRTx2Gp7SXa3D9vm8EkO1g)

The docs says exactly that

> Existential types that can be expressed using only wildcards (but not
> forSome) are still supported, but are treated as refined types

**QUESTION:** Why doesn't my example work. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: No `forSome` syntax cannot be replaced by wildcard, even in Scala 2. So in Scala 3 when its disabled, there will be no alternative. In your case just use `val t: Test[Int]`. There's no additional benefits of using existential type.

Comment: I agree with @texasbruce. When you write `val foo: Foo`, it's pretty much the same as saying `foo` is some `T` where `T` is a subtype of `Foo`. Existentials are not necessary here (and rarely are anywhere, which is why they were dropped).

Comment: `T forSome { type T <: Test[Int] }` is just `Test[Int]`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin This was pointed out by texasbruce earlier.